# hybrid app first install and launch OK,then kill process, restart, crash error: [base.apk] WV.O5.onResult

Tags: google-chrome, webview, crash

backtrace:
#00  pc 0x000000000256a0de  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#01  pc 0x00000000025bbff1  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#02  pc 0x00000000025bbd6b  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#03  pc 0x0000000002f36b6f  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#04  pc 0x0000000002dc67b3  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#05  pc 0x0000000002dc67a1  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#06  pc 0x0000000002f2c107  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#07  pc 0x0000000002dc6035  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#08  pc 0x0000000002dc5eeb  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#09  pc 0x0000000002d96835  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#10  pc 0x00000000037aaab7  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#11  pc 0x00000000038c337f  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#12  pc 0x00000000000dc519  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
#13  pc 0x00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
#14  pc 0x000000000042e56b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
#15  pc 0x00000000000dffcb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194)
#16  pc 0x0000000000210a09  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280)
#17  pc 0x000000000020c34b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+774)
#18  pc 0x0000000000425c87  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+310)
#19  pc 0x00000000000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
#20  pc 0x000000000009171c  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-jzTaDhe4uw9YbR5S3GlPGA==/base.apk (WV.O5.onResult+44)
#21  pc 0x0000000000424e19  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1432)
#22  pc 0x00000000000d2a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
#23  pc 0x00000000000a2834  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-jzTaDhe4uw9YbR5S3GlPGA==/base.apk (WV.cb.run+8)
#24  pc 0x00000000001ec285  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.4051875684531665263)+192)
#25  pc 0x00000000001f0a69  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+124)
#26  pc 0x0000000000417fc9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+808)
#27  pc 0x00000000000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
#28  pc 0x00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
#29  pc 0x000000000042e457  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250)
#30  pc 0x00000000000dffb7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+174)
#31  pc 0x00000000003701f7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54)
#32  pc 0x00000000003710e1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+304)
#33  pc 0x00000000002a0739  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+480)
#34  pc 0x00000000025e7ced  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#35  pc 0x00000000030610ef  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#36  pc 0x000000000306108f  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#37  pc 0x00000000025eef7d  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#38  pc 0x00000000025ed585  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#39  pc 0x00000000019bbc2b  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#40  pc 0x0000000002ee4dff  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#41  pc 0x0000000002ee4dcb  /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_599308030-Tj0ScAUCYP2HxAMVPCajqQ==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (BuildId: 431b47d63824d8e1029d4435258a75b01260bedd)
#42  pc 0x0000000000010867  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+666)
#43  pc 0x0000000000010553  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+30)
#44  pc 0x00000000000d285f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+24)
#45  pc 0x000000000119a295  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+92)
#46  pc 0x0000000001396dfb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.MessageQueue.next+202)
#47  pc 0x00000000013930cd  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+580)
#48  pc 0x0000000000bee017  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+806)
#49  pc 0x00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
#50  pc 0x000000000042e56b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
#51  pc 0x00000000000dffcb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194)
#52  pc 0x00000000003701f7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54)
#53  pc 0x00000000003714fb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+850)
#54  pc 0x000000000031e79f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+30)
#55  pc 0x00000000005f8f17  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+110)
#56  pc 0x0000000001d951cb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)
#57  pc 0x0000000001daff19  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1832)
#58  pc 0x00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
#59  pc 0x000000000042e56b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
#60  pc 0x00000000000dffcb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194)
#61  pc 0x00000000003701f7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54)
#62  pc 0x0000000000370037  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+290)
#63  pc 0x00000000002bc9a9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+460)
#64  pc 0x00000000000803b9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+28)
#65  pc 0x00000000000828d5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vectorandroid::String8 const&, bool)+624)
#66  pc 0x0000000000002307  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+706)
#67  pc 0x0000000000059999  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+68)
#68  pc 0x000000000000202f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38)
#69  pc 0x0000000000004456

my app target 33  , agp 7+